# Opencv installation problems

Tags: opencv, macos-high-sierra

I am trying to follow a guide to install Opencv however I am having problems.

I am following this guide:

https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/12/19/install-opencv-3-on-macos-with-homebrew-the-easy-way/

However there is an addendum when it reaches this point:

**Update — 15 May 2017:**
Which then sends you to this page:

[This Page](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/05/15/resolving-macos-opencv-homebrew-install-errors/)

As stated in this guide I installed OpenCV3 using this command:
brew install opencv3 --with-contrib --with-python3

I then stepped back to the original install guide [here](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/12/19/install-opencv-3-on-macos-with-homebrew-the-easy-way/)

However when checking my site packages using this line:

ls -l /usr/local/opt/opencv3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/

The directory is not found.
I then tried to cd to this directory one step at a time and found in my 'opt' directory that some of the folders were names incorrectly or at least different than to be expected.

I have two opencv folders:
opencv 
opencv@3

I also have three python folders:
python3
python@2
python@3

Should I rename the opencv and python folders? If so how?

Mac OS High Sierra

Comment: make sure you install numpy. However I would recommend to install OpenCV using CMake.

Comment: I suggest don't rename any folders if you use brew to install libraries.

Comment: You can test or check your installation of OpenCV by doing the following in python terminal: 
>>> import cv2
>>> cv2.__version__

Comment: @Howard GENG I can import opencv in both python 2 and python 3. OpenCV version is 3.4.3

Comment: Then you have successfully installed OpenCV.

Comment: And now I can't import opencv when in a virtual environment :-) Another post.

Comment: In order to install something in the virtual environment, I suggest you could look at this page: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip